# Enumerable method like Intersect() w/ partial compare

Tags: c#

C# code:

```
string[] a1 = {"Yank","Yankee","MLB"};
string[] a2 = {"yan","yankeedoodle","m"};
```

I would like to search for a2 strings in a1 where

- `a2[yank]` would yield `"Yank"` and `"Yankee"`
- `a2[yankeedoodle]` yields `null`
- `a2[m]` would yield `"MLB"`

Something similar to a `strstr()` ignoring case

`Intersect()` returns full matches, I want partial.

Is there a method or just do it the long way?

Comment: `a2[yank]` is `a2[yan]`?!

Comment: How many strings are in these arrays? If the number is relatively small, then the naive method (call `string.Contains` on every member of `a1` for every member of `a2`) will work well. If one or both of the arrays is exceptionally large, then you need something more involved.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is pretty specific, so it'd doubtful anything pre-built exists for something like this. You just need to write the logic, something like:

```
a2.ToDictionary(
    prefix => prefix, 
    prefix => a1.Where(str => str.StartsWith(
        prefix, 
        true, 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to lookup all partial matches from the second in the first collection in a case insensitive manner. Presuming that *partial* means sub-string:

```
var A2ToA1lookup = a2.ToLookup(
    s2 => s2, 
    s2 => a1.Where(s1 => s1.IndexOf(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

You can use it like a dictionary, but if the key is not found it yields an empty sequence:

```
foreach (var matches in A2ToA1lookup["yan"])          
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", matches));      // Yank,Yankee
foreach (var matches in A2ToA1lookup["yankeedoodle"])
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", matches));      // -- String.Empty --
foreach (var matches in A2ToA1lookup["m"])
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", matches));      // MLB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with LINQ:

```
 var results = a1.Where(e1 => a2.Any(e2 => e1.ToUpper().Contains(e2.ToUpper())));
```